# How to debug a jQuery AJAX call that is made to a Sinatra application?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using Ruby, Sinatra and a Postgres. I am working with the Plivo api.

There is a search page (search.erb) where a jQuery script collects data from a search box and then passes it to query the api.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(".localsearch").click(function() {
        var country_iso = $("#local").val();
        var region = $("#region").val();
        var prefix = $("#prefix").val();
        alert(country_iso + ' ' + region + ' ' + prefix)
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/local/data",
        data: { 'country_iso' : country_iso,  'region' : region,  'prefix' : prefix },
        success: function(data){
            window.location.href = '/local'
        }
      });
});
```

If the url is "/local/data" the params are passed but Sinatra does not recognise the erb page which is local.erb, alternatively if the url is just "local" the params are not passed (I have checked this in the console) so the result does not render on the local.erb page.

The ruby code is:

```
get '/search' do
    erb :search
end

get '/local/data' do
      #country_iso = 'US'
      #region = 'NY'
      #prefix = '646'
      country_iso =  params[:country_iso]
      region = params[:region]
      prefix = params[:prefix]
      p = RestAPI.new(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN)
      params = {'country_iso' => country_iso, 'region' => region, 'prefix' => prefix, 'limit' => 1}
      warn params.inspect   
      response = p.get_number_group(params)
      obj = response.last
      pp obj
      @stock = obj["objects"][0]["stock"]
      @region = obj["objects"][0]["region"]
      @prefix = obj["objects"][0]["prefix"]
      @voice_rate = obj["objects"][0]["voice_rate"]

      erb :local
end
```

I am not sure exactly what is going wrong here but I suspect that the problem is the route along which the params are passed, as suggested above. I think I need a separate section which scripts what is supposed to happen but I don't know what to call that or how to separate / include it with the get '/local' do section.

For example, in the ruby snippet above, if the erb is local.erb should the top be '/local' and not 'local/data'? If just 'local' then how do I pass the params?

Very grateful, as always, for all comments and help. Thank you. There are no problems with the jquery or the api call so the difficulty does not lie there.

Comment: long question... can you add some error? can you show some curl calls to clarify which routes you are talking about?

Comment: if you suppose that the problem is not jquery, please leave the parts out that are not relevant

Comment: with the get '/local/data' do route the console shows this: http://justpaste.it/2myi and the local.erb page returns no error but the required data (region, prefix, voice_rate etc.) is not rendered. With get '/local' do nothing happens and jquery url '/local', this is the result: http://justpaste.it/2mym because the params are not reaching the api call.  The url is part of the problem.

Comment: the main part of my question is this: should I define the way the jquery is processed within the get '/local' do script segment or separately. If separately how can I make sure that the desired result is rendered in html on the local.erb page? If jquery url (and ruby) is '/local' no api call is made because the params are not passed, if they are both '/local/data' the params are passed but nothing is rendered on the local.erb page.

Comment: not sure if I understand, are you talking about having an /api namespace ? Is the JSON processing a problem? Is passing JSON a problem?

Comment: no it's not a JSON parsing problem. The api is provided by Plivo (a 3rd party). Please can you see my comments lower down too? The question is this : should the code which tells what to do with the params be included in the get '/local' do script block or in another place. If in another place, how can the results be rendered on the local.erb page. If the jquery url is '/local/data' the params are passed if it is just 'local' the params are not passed. When the params are passed a succsefful call is made otherwise not. The result of a correctcall is justpaste.it/2myi

Comment: ok, I think I get your question now. So, you want to render JSON instead of HTML when accessing the action? Have a look at: http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/json.html

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, you can try:

- use `console.log(...)` instead of `alert(...)` to track the request processing (before, after the request has been made)
- try the jQuery Ajax call from the browser on a terminal with `curl`, e.g. you can try: 
  `curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:9292/search -d "country_iso=US"` and see if this requests is entering the action correctly
- raise an exception for debugging to check that you pass a certain code point, and show the stacktrace of the Sinatra log here

Your second issue seems to be a problem with understanding how to setup nested routes:

Try:

```
get '/local' do
  # ... setup your view instance variables here
  erb :local
end
```

Comment: sorry, I am not sure how to do what you describe above ... when I enter the string above google does a search for it which I don't think is what we want.

Comment: this is what I get on my local.erb page NoMethodError at /local
undefined method `[]' for #<RestClient::BadRequest:0x96274e8>

I am sure the issue is related to the "route" or url along which the params are passed: '/local' or '/local/data', if the latter the params arrive if the former not. So the question is still, I think, is it correct to script the action taken with the params in the get 'local' do segment or should it be done in a different code block?